# What are the ways for creating a Django project structure

Tags: python, django

I have been following Django tutorials.  It says I can create projects using the following command:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

And then I can create apps using

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```

This gives me a standard project structure.  When creating real life websites/portal is this how project structures are?  Are there other ways of creating projects?

Comment: There are nearly infinite ways to possibly structure the project. The standard structure works and is what you want unless you're trying to confuse newcomers.

Comment: Thanks.  I will go with the standard project structure.

Answer (score 0):

In Django you can change the structure somewhat providing you add your apps to your settings.py file.

The structure is mostly just a recommended way, so you could choose to mess around with it, but most people don't mess around too much otherwise it will throw other people who are used to the standard structure.

You could take a look at how Ruby On Rails structures their projects for some alternative thoughts: https://www.sitepoint.com/a-quick-study-of-the-rails-directory-structure/